# In character Array Compiler giving extra space to store Null character but in string it's showing error

Tags: c++, string

char ch[5] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'}; This is not showing any error But char ch[5] = "abcde" showing error .Why?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    char ch[5] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'};
    int i;
    for( i = 0; ch[i] != '\0'; i++){
        cout << ch[i] << ' ';
    }
return 0;
}
```

Output:- a b c d e
In this case while loop is terminating implies null character is there but since I have given the size 5 so where it has stored this null character?

But when I wrote this program:-

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    char ch[5] = "abcde";
    int i;
    for( i = 0; ch[i] != '\0'; i++){
        cout << ch[i] << endl;
    }
return 0;
}
```

In this case it's showing error:- initializer-string for array of chars is too long [-fpermissive]
Please explain why this is happening.

Answer (score 3):

> loop is terminating implies null character is there but since I have given the size 5 so where it has stored this null character?

There's no null character in this array, you only get one when you use double quotes (like in your second snippet).

You accessed the array out of bounds and got lucky (the very next byte in the memory happened to be null, and [nasal demons](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html) failed to be summoned this time).

> But char ch[5] = "abcde" showing error .Why?

Because there's no room for the null character.

---

FYI, C is less strict in this regard compared to C++ and allows `char ch[5] = "abcde";`. No null character is added in this case.

Comment: I tried char ch[5] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'};
    int i;
    for( i = 0; ch[i] != '\0'; i++){
        cout << ch[i] << ' ';
    } on many editors and many machines but it's running absolutely fine on each of them.I can't be lucky all the time so I guess some reason is there behind this behaviour.

Comment: @Deeksha Accessing an array out of bounds is undefined behavior, period. If you know assembly, you can look at the assembly your compiler generates to see why it always works, but in the end it's still UB.

Answer (score 0):

```
char ch[6] = "abcde";
```

Try this. It needs an extra index for storing `'\0'`.